# Einstein-Hilbert action and antisymmetry of derivative of $g_{\mu \nu}$ in Christoffel symbols

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-principle, action

In the context of the Einstein-Hilbert action $S_{EH}$, we have to compute $\delta R_{\mu\nu}$ and at a moment, we have a term $\delta \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\alpha \mu}$ to compute. I'm wondering why do we have,

\begin{align}
\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\alpha \mu} 
  &= \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha \rho} \left( g_{\alpha \rho, \mu} + g_{\mu \rho, \alpha} - g_{\alpha \mu, \rho} \right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha \rho} g_{\alpha \rho, \mu}
\end{align}

because of the antisymmetry of $g_{\mu \rho, \alpha}$ and $g_{\alpha \mu, \rho}$ in $\alpha \leftrightarrow \rho$

I mean, where does this antisymmetry comes from ? It is not true in all generalities, am I right ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the term in parentheses
$$
g^{\alpha\rho}(g_{\mu\rho,\alpha}-g_{\alpha\mu,\rho})
$$
can be written as
$$
 g^{\alpha\rho}(g_{\rho\mu,\alpha}-g_{\alpha\mu,\rho})
$$
which is manifestly antisymmetric in $\rho$ and $\alpha$. So, as $g^{\alpha\rho}$ is symmetric, you get zero.